# LWJGL starts to run low FPS on Display

Tags: graphics, overloading, lwjgl, frame-rate

I'm having this problem with LWJGL. I have a simple game and all works fine. My main loop is calculating when it should render and update my game. It stays constant 59-60 fps. The problem comes in opengl I guess. After random amounts of time my whole game starts to run at very low fps. My game loop still calculates 60 fps and updates, but what I see on screen doesn't match it. I'm guessing I overload openGL. I'm clearing color buffer bit and depth buffer(though I don't do any depth). Is there anything more I need to clear?

Answer (score 0):

It's king of tough to say what may be wrong with your program without actually looking at the code. Clearing off the screen is one thing but it really shouldn't have the biggest impact so unfortunately I can't really tell you without any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is a problem with slow hardware?  This seems like a trivial "I have a slow graphics card" or "I have a lot of things open in the background" kind of problem.  Also note that on most laptops if you shake it the hard drive will lock up for a few seconds, causing stuttering.

As Andrew said you can't really pinpoint this sort of problem without code.